# Cannot return ArrayList of Lists from Jax-ws Web Service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, arraylist, jaxb

I want to return ArrayList which contains List objects, through JAX-WS.

This is my method

```
public ArrayList allTokens() {
 ArrayList allItems = new ArrayList();

 List myList1 = new ArrayList();
 myList1.add("Indunil");
 myList1.add(22);

 List myList2 = new ArrayList();
 myList2.add("Tharanga");
 myList2.add(20);

 //adding lists to all items
 allItems.add(myList1);
 allItems.add(myList2);

 return(allItems);
}
```

Following error is showing when I call web service:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this
>   context. javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor
>   any of its super class is known to this context.]     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:325)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:278)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:380)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:92)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:525)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:106)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:91)
>     at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)     at
>   sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)    at
>   com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)  at
>   sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
>     at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)     at
>   sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this
>   context. javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor
>   any of its super class is known to this context.]     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:269)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.BridgeImpl.marshal(BridgeImpl.java:100)
>     at com.sun.xml.bind.api.Bridge.marshal(Bridge.java:141)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:317)
>     ... 18 more Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class
>   java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this
>   context. javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor
>   any of its super class is known to this context.  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:246)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:261)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:653)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:65)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:155)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:264)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class
>   java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this
>   context.  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:594)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:648)
>     ... 27 more

I tried some JAXB, but didn't able to solve my problem. I don't know how to do JXAB properly. This is for my final project of my degree.

Comment: could you share implementation of method allTokens() ?

Comment: Which one do you want? This is the method in my Server side.
I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0.59

Comment: It would be much easier to either use a `List<NameNumber>` with NameNumber being a class for representing the list elements *properly*, or just a flat list, i.e., storing `"Indunil",  `22`, `"Tharanga"`, `20`, etc. into one `List<Object>`, assuming that you are able to tell from the pattern string-int-string-int what is what.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the List (which is parent of ArrayList) will work . Please try with below code:

```
public static  List<List> allTokens() {
     List<List> allItems = new ArrayList<List>();

     List<String> myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     myList1.add("Indunil");
     myList1.add("22");

     List<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
     myList1.add("Tharanga");
     myList1.add("20");

     //adding lists to all items
     allItems.add(myList1);
     allItems.add(myList2);

     return(allItems);
}
```

Comment: I want to send different data types inside list.

List myList1 = new ArrayList();
myList1.add("Indunil"); // string
myList1.add(22); // int

Comment: Ok, i've updated the question with complete exception.